# How can I increase the height of UITableViewCell dynamiclly

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have an UITableView which includes a list of UITableViewCells. And I set the heights of UITableViewCells in method `(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

However, I need to increase the height of `UITableViewCell` when it is selected. For example, the height of `UITableViewCell` needs to increase 100 pixels when the cell is selected, does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Store selected index in your controller.
2. Return cell's height depending on that index:

   ```
   CGFloat height = 30.0f;
   ...
   -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
       return indexPath.row == selectedIndex ? height+100 : height;
   }
   ```
3. Refresh tableview geometry in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method (empty block between `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` does the trick):

   ```
   - (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
       index = indexPath.row;
       [tableView beginUpdates];
       [tableView endUpdates];      
   }
   ```

Comment: Shouldn't he reload that cell?

Comment: You need to reload the cell only if its contents change. on practice it must be so indeed...

Comment: Actually in that case he needs to reload 2 cells - the newly selected and the previous one

Comment: Nice. I got the same confusion, and first I try the [tableview reloaddata] method to refresh geometry which takes seconds. beginUpdates/endUpdates is the better and right way.

Answer (score 0):

Make your delegate method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

return the (new) correct height and make the table view reload the given path.