# iOS7 Adjust TableViewCell's height dynamically based on the height of image downloaded from API

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How can I adjust a `UITableViewCell's` height dynamically based on the height of an image downloaded from an API?

I tried to use `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath` but failed.

FYI, I am using AFNetworking to get the images' url from api and I use SDWebImage to get the image data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resize the Table cell height as per downloaded image height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092340/resize-the-table-cell-height-as-per-downloaded-image-height)

Answer (score 0):

Set height from `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIImage *image = (UIImage *)[tableImageDict objectForKey:
                                 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i,%i",
                                  indexPath.row,indexPath.section]];


    if (image != nil)
    {
        return image.size.height; // you can set your size by taking from sdwebimage
    }
    else{
        return 44.0;
    }
}
```

See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15269526/3202193) related to it.